How to trigger Azure Pipeline after successful push to Artifact Feed?
I need to trigger a Azure Pipeline after the successful push of Artifact NuGet Feed. I tried to use resources in YAML as below with the help of service connection. But while saving itself getting the error as "Only GitHub type service connections with PAT authentication scheme are supported for GitHub packages".
resources:
  packages:
    - package: MyPackage
      type: nuget
      name: MyFeed/MyPackage
      version: '*'
      trigger: true
      connection: 'NuGet-Conn'

Please let me know how to fix this issue. Otherwise please let me know any other way to trigger the pipeline.
Update:
First Pipeline:
- script: |
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myVar;isOutput=true]value123"
    name: SetVariable
    displayName: 'Set variable'

Second Pipeline:
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: sourcePipeline
      project: TestPrj
      source: FirstPipeline
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - "*"

variables:
  - name: myVariable
    value: $[ resources.pipeline.sourcePipeline.outputs['Job1.SetVariable.myVar'] ]

jobs:
- job: Job2
  displayName: 'Job2'

  steps:
  - script: |
      echo "Value: $(myVar)"
      echo $(resources.pipeline.sourcePipeline.sourceBranch)

In this approach, I am not able to get the value in "myVar". Please let me know how the value.
Thanks.

According to Packages resource definition, package resource is designed for GitHub instead of Azure Artifact. That's why you see error Only GitHub type service connections with PAT authentication scheme are supported for GitHub packages.

You can consume NuGet and npm GitHub packages as resources in YAML pipelines

If your package is published from the Azure pipeline, you can trigger your target pipeline use this one. See the details from Trigger one pipeline after another.
If your package is published somewhere else, for example from local machine, there is no out-of-the-box way to trigger the pipeline by Azure Artifact. You can submit a feature request from Developer Community to request for such feature and share the link of it here, so that others who want the same feature can follow and submit a vote to increase its priority.
As a possible workaround, you may consider classic release pipeline and select Azure Artifact as the artifact. However, it's not perfect and has some limits.

Steps:


Select Azure Artifact as the artifact
Feed: Your target feed
Package type: NuGet
Package: The package you want to check updates.

Enable CI trigger for the selected package.


Result:
A new release is created every time a new version of the selected package is published.


Limits:

It's only supported in the classic release pipeline.
The trigger is based on the package instead of the feed. You may need to add multiple packages as the artifact.




Update:
For your question "how to pass parameters to the second pipeline based on the execution of first pipeline",
You can run REST API Runs - Run Pipeline to trigger the target build and pass the parameters. See the example below for reference.
First Pipeline: Ensure to replace { } with your actual values.
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: |
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myVar;isOutput=true]value123"
  name: SetVariable
  displayName: 'Set variable'

- script: |
    echo "The value of  myVar is :$(SetVariable.myVar)"

- powershell: |
      $token = "{PAT}"
      $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
      $url="https://dev.azure.com/{OrgName}/{ProjecctName}/_apis/pipelines/{PipelineID}/runs?api-version=7.1"
      $body = "{
          `"templateParameters`": {
              `"customVar1`": `"$(SetVariable.myVar)`",
              `"customVar2`": `"test`"

          }
      }"
      $head = @{ Authorization ="Basic $token" }
      Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Headers $head -Body $body -ContentType application/json

Second Pipeline:
parameters:
- name: customVar1
  type: string
  default: ''
- name: customVar2
  type: string
  default: ''

trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: |
    echo 'The value of parameter customVar1 is ' ${{parameters.customVar1}}
    echo 'The value of parameter customVar2 is ' ${{parameters.customVar2}}
  displayName: 'Echo the parameters'


Result:


Thanks Ziyang. I tried "resources pipelines". Both pipelines are in same project. But second pipeline is not triggered after first pipeline completion.

Also please let me know how to pass parameters to the second pipeline based on the execution of first pipeline.


"Both pipelines are in same project. But second pipeline is not triggered after first pipeline completion" - Please share the latest yaml file of your pipeline in the question. Is your first pipeline successful? Do you configure pipeline resource in the template? 2. "how to pass parameters to the second pipeline based on the execution of first pipeline" - The resource pipeline has some predefined variables that you can use directly in the triggered pipeline.


If these predefined variables do not meet your needs, you need to consider other workarounds, because it is not supported to pass parameters directly from the resource pipeline to the triggered pipeline. For example, a). Run REST API Variablegroups - Update in the first pipeline to update the variable group. Then consume this variable group in the triggered pipeline.

b). Don't use pipeline resource to trigger the target pipeline but Run REST API Builds - Queue to trigger the target build and pass the parameters.

I cannot use variable group for my requirement. And I have tried another approach which I updated in my actual query. In which I tried to print custom variable and predefined variable. But both values are empty. Please let me know what I have missed.

You can't directly pass variables to another pipeline like resources.pipeline.sourcePipeline.outputs['Job1.SetVariable.myVar']. There isn't such syntax in Azure Devops. As I mentioned in the comments above, Don't use pipeline resource to trigger the target pipeline but Run REST API Runs - Run Pipeline to trigger the target build and pass the parameters.  I will share an example in my answer later.

May I know why you are not suggesting to use pipeline resource? And as you mentioned please share an example. Thanks Ziyang.

"May I know why you are not suggesting to use pipeline resource" - You want to pass parameters from one pipeline to another, but there isn't out-of-box way can do this. There isn't such resources.pipeline.sourcePipeline.outputs['Job1.SetVariable.myVar'] syntax` in Azure DevOps. I have shared two suggestions. The first one is to use pipeline resource to trigger the pipeline and pass variables via variable group. But you said you can't use the variable group.

The second one is to call REST API to trigger another pipeline. If you use pipeline resource in the second pipeline at the same time, when the first pipeline is completed the second pipeline will be triggered twice. One is triggered by pipeline resource and don't have the variables created in the first pipeline; another is triggered by REST API and can get the corresponding variables. In this situation, there is no need to use pipeline resource. Hope these are clear for you.
